# Combining NULL and numeric value in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to replicate the following R code in Shiny

```
if ((is.null(num.iters)) || (num.iters == 1))
```

I tried this but I get an

```
character(0)
Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

using

```
        numericInput(inputId = "num.iters",
                            label = "Number of iterations to run (num.iters)",
                            value = NULL,
                            min = 1,
                            max = 1)
```

The problem is that `NULL` is not numeric. The intent is for `NULL` to run all iterations. Unfortunately, how many iterations to run is not known in advance since my app involves stochastic simulations.
I saw this post, which involves a similar problem: [How do I use the NULL Value as a variable call in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271132/how-do-i-use-the-null-value-as-a-variable-call-in-r-shiny)

but I want to combine `NULL` and a numeric value with only one input label, which is a bit different than the response to the linked post.

Is this possible?

Comment: use `NA` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: Do you need to reference the input as `input$num.iters` in your if statement?

Comment: Also, it's a bad habit to use `.` in object names in shiny, because you can run into problems with how they're interpreted in the translation to JS (particularly a problem for apps using modules).

Comment: You have brackets around is.null and your equates to.

Comment: @Oliver I can't simply use NA because I call R code from a function that uses NULL.

Comment: @phalteman Yes. I reference it as such in server.R within a call to `observeEvent(...)`

Comment: @Wakka The `if` statement is not part of my Shiny app. It's just R code I want to emulate in Shiny.

Comment: use `NA` and check `is.na` and then forward a `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numericInput` default to `NA` when it's empty. Maybe a workaround can be:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "num.iters",
    label = "Number of iterations to run (num.iters)",
    value = NA,
    min = 1,
    max = 1
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if ((is.na(input$num.iters)) || (input$num.iters == 1)) {
      print(as.null(input$num.iters))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```